# Auto Save to Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

If you add a file to Dropbox via an automated method, will Dropbox automatically sync it to your online account, or do you have to manually initiate the sync?

**More Details:**

I'm looking into setting up a system that will allow me to wirelessly transmit a file to my Dropbox folder on my computer. It will be kind of a photo booth setup where there will be a line of people having their picture taken. Every time a photo is taken, it will be automatically transferred to the Dropbox folder via wifi. Then, I want the photo to automatically be uploaded to the cloud without me having to even touch the computer. Once it's uploaded, I have another system that will transfer the file to a site where it can be downloaded by the person. I want them to be able to walk away from having their photo taken and within minutes be able to access it online (without me ever touching the computer) which is why I need to know if there's a way to have dropbox automatically push the file to the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make any manual effort. Once a file is in your Dropbox folder, it'll be synced to any computer that has access to your Dropbox folder.